# How to develope a Virtual com port c++

Tags: c++, serial-port, virtual

I have been told to develop a virtual com port so an app the company has can read off com "comCompanyNameV1".. I tried to pick apart com0com, but it seem so incomplete I'm finding I have to kludge around large parts of it and I have yet to get anything to come close to compiling. Mostly because the tools that are outlined to use to build aren't available anymore.

Can anyone point me in a direction to allow me to create a virtual com port that?  I really don't want to have to spend a month trying to figure out how to do it from scratch.

Oh.. if some knows how to get it done in languages other than c++ I'm good with that too.

---

I forgot to mention.  The actual hardware might be attached to com1 but I still have to have the app read on the custom named com.  It's a third party app and we've got no idea why they picked a strange named com, but they did.

Comment: Windows XP originally, but it should be windows 7 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Does [How to create a Virtual Com1 port in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209541/how-to-create-a-virtual-com1-port-in-windows) help at all?

This is a link to SDK that may make it easier - http://www.download32.com/virtual-serial-port-sdk-i11199.html

In reply to your comments. Its been a long time since I did anything with the DDK but googling indicates that there may be a serial port example in there. I cannot be certain. However logically speaking the virtual com port should be an NT entity with a user mode component (already supplied). So I'd suspect you'd write a kernel driver that would then communicate with the USER mode process as you see fit.

Comment: No, the other questioncame up in my search.. There isn't really an answer on that question. The other link is a pay-for kind of thing.  I think the reason for me having to do it was to avoid licensing issues, and to make sure we have more control over it than most third party software give.

Comment: I found this document.  It tells me what the samples are with the DDK install.

http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/gstart/gs_design_9lk7.htm

Comment: That's way old. Download the latest and see.

Comment: It seems odd to me that all the samples would be built with a make file.. Is that right to you?  I would figure it would integrate with VS.  I would sorely love a project I could open.. Oh and to winge a bit.  I wish coders would put more value on commenting their code.  Especially when it's set to be open source. (for those that don't)

Comment: Nope. (in my day lol :) Drivers were always built with with make and build. You can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037343/how-can-i-build-a-driver-using-visual-studio as to how to make it work with VS.