# How to Configure Visual Studio 2008 for Compiling Drivers?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, configure, drivers

I configured visual studio 2008 for compiling drivers, but still showing lots of syntax errors for header file for ctype.h and excpt.h

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: i already generated .sys file using checked build environment but was not getting setting to generate .sys file through visual studio 2008 so just wanted some guidance but i figured it out and also posted the answer for that hope it will surely help some beginner for windows device driver development..

Answer (score 0):

```
I configured with following settings :

Setup Visual Studio 2008.

    Setup ddk (wdk).

    Add to Visual Studio paths DDK include files, libs and bins, In VS goto tools ->options->Project and solutions->VC++ directories-> add path to your ddk Include files,Executeable file,Library file 

    Create new empty "Win32 project" and add source file (i.e. Hello_World.c).

    Configure project properties (All Configurations):

    C\C++ - General - Debug Information Format = Program Database (/Zi)
    C\C++ - Optimization - Disabled
    C\C++ - Preprocessor - Preprocessor Definitions = _X86_;_DEBUG;DBG
    C\C++ - Code Generation - Enable Minimum Rebuild = Yes(/Gm)
    C\C++ - Code Generation - Enable C++ Exceptions = No
    C\C++ - Code Generation - Basic Runtime Checks = Default
    C\C++ - Code Generation - Buffer Security Check = No (/GS-)
    C\C++ - Advanced - Calling Convention = __stdcall (/Gz)
    C\C++ - Advanced - Compile As = Compile as C Code (/TC) [if you are going to use plain   
    C\C++ - Command Line - it must show /Od /D "_X86_" /D "_DEBUG" /D "DBG" /D "_MBCS" /Gm /MDd /GS- /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /Zi /Gz /TC /showIncludes /errorReport:prompt                                                         C]
    Linker - General - Output File = $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).sys
    Linker - General - Enable Incremental Linking = Default
    Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies = ntoskrnl.lib hal.lib $(NOINHERIT) [add     
                                               needed libs here e.g. ntoskrnl.lib hal.lib]
    Linker - Input - Ignore All Default Libraries = Yes (/NODEFAULTLIB)
    Linker - Manifest File - Generate Manifest = No
    Linker - System - Sub System = Native (/SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE)
    Linker - System - Driver = Driver (/DRIVER)
    Linker - Advanced - Entry Point = DriverEntry
    Linker - Advanced - Base Address = 0x10000
    Linker - Advanced - Randomized Base Address = Default
    Linker - Advanced - Data Execution Prevention (DEP) = Default
```

Now build solution for your driver code with current settings..

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have properly added Visual Studio header file,library files,executable files paths to DDK directory..