# Custom Compiler with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, wdk

In older Visual Studios (e.g. 2008) there was a "Tool Build Order" menu.  And from that menu I could select to not use the C/C++ Compiler, and instead use my own in the Custom Build Tool.

I want to do the same in Visual Studio 2013, but that menu appears to be gone.  How do I get the same effect?  My goal is to have 1 target (e.g. Debug) that builds using the Visual Studio 2013 compiler, so that I can get all the nice code analysis output; and then a separate target (e.g. DDK7600 Free) that uses a different compiler for doing my actual releases.

Comment: That dialog was gonzo in VS2010 with its drastic overhaul of the C++ build system.  There's no substitute for it.  The DDK compiler wasn't different from the VS compiler so it isn't exactly clear why you'd switch.  VS2013 now directly supports [building drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), best way to get ahead.  Video [is here](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/HW-235T).

Answer (score 1):

Just right click the Solution node and select "Project Build Order". (for build order)

For DDK compilation in VS 2013:
[how can i build a driver using visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037343/how-can-i-build-a-driver-using-visual-studio)
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554644(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Project Build Order let's me choose the order projects in the solution build.  I want the "Tool Build Order" menu.  It's a separate and distinct menu.  And if I could get an older DDK version to build with the newer VS then I'd be happy as well, but your link doesn't appear to address that.

Comment: @omghai2u, WDK 8.1 from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx integrates with VS. I don't think VS2013 will support older DDK

Comment: Right.  How about the "Tool Build Order" menu?

Comment: Yeah, again, I'm not sure how to explain this any other way, but that menu appears to have been removed.  "Build Order" doesn't exist.  The closest is "Project Dependencies" -> "Project Build Order".  But that does not include the "Tool Build Order" menu.  The link you sent me is talking about Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: In the link from this answer there is a part: "_The WDK now uses the same compiler and build tools that you use to build Visual Studio projects._" Thus it would seem that using separate compiler is no longer needed?

Comment: @omghai2u, actually I think this is the new method for VS 2013: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293705.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770593.aspx